# ng-repeat over a non-array/object / dealing with arrays and non-arrays the same way

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Often times I want to deal with both arrays and single objects in the same fashion. For example I have the property of an object that can either be an array or just a string (look at the `scale` property):

```
[
 {
    "name": "Experiment type14",
    "id": "00000000014",
    "scale": ["Whole Brain", "Cell"],

 },
 {
    "name": "Experiment type15",
    "id": "00000000015",
    "scale": "Cell",
 }
]
```

What I want is to show my `scale` like here:

```
<span ng-repeat="scale in experimentType.scale">
 <!--some decoration here--> {{scale}}
</span>
```

Of course this won't work for a single string values. Is there any elegant way not to worry whether I'm dealing with a string or with an array?

Comment: Personally I think a filter is the best way to handle this. One that *unifys* the data, so that your view has to only *worry* about one kind of format.

Comment: I'm thinking about smth like that too. I love how it's done in jquery: you just wrap stuff in `$()` and forget about the object/array worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your custom filter, please see below

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

function MainCtrl() {
  this.message = "Welcome";
  this.data = [{
    "id": "00000000014",
    "name": "Experiment type14",        
    "scale": ["Whole Brain", "Cell"],
   },{
    "id": "00000000015",
    "name": "Experiment type15",
    "scale": "Cell",
   }];  
}

function toArray() {
  return  function(input) {
    console.log(input);
    if (angular.isArray(input)) {
      return input;
    } else {
      return [input];
    }
  };
}

angular.module("app").controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);
angular.module("app").filter('toArray', toArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div class="container">
       <h3>{{ vm.message }}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="scale in item.scale | toArray">{{ scale }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my best try. I just implement the following function in the scope:

```
$scope.toArrayIfNot = function (input) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Array]') {
            return input;
        }
        return [input];
    };
```

I then use it like that:

```
<span ng-repeat="scale in toArrayIfNot(experimentType.scale)">
 <!--some decoration here--> {{scale}}
</span>
```